# Join new rows [SQL]

Tags: sql

I have a left table with unique rows, and a right table that has those same unique rows + new unique ones. What's the right query to keep the unique rows from the left table (better quality data), and bring in only the new rows from the right table that don't exist in the left one already?

Comment: What SQL have you tried to achieve what you're trying to do?

Comment: And what RDBMS?

Comment: how can you talk about data quality if the data is the same in both tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT a.id, a.data
FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.id, b.data
FROM table_b
WHERE b.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just UNION them. Depending on your DBMS, UNION will drop duplicates and UNION ALL will preserve them.

Comment: How does something like this get an upvote?  If the rows were exactly the same, then it doesn't matter which table the row comes from.

Answer (score 0):

If you (for some reason) need to use joins instead of union, you *could* use a `FULL JOIN` and use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` on each column.

This will leave everything from the left table plus everything from the right table that doesn't exist on the left.